# How to simulate keypress event from Qt on none-Qt apps

Tags: linux, qt, keyboard-shortcuts

How to simulate CTRL+SHIFT+T from qt app on focused non-qt app ?

One option is libfakekey any other options ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's no direct way of doing this in Qt. Maybe these articles would help

[Qt: How to send an event to the operating/window system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174570/qt-how-to-send-an-event-to-the-operating-window-system)

http://www.qtforum.org/article/9075/sending-keys.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, yup it seems to be so... However I've implemented my code using libfakekey ...